# Maven activeByDefault profile being overwritten by another profile

Tags: java, maven, native

I am trying to use Maven for a Java native project, using it to determine whether the current system is 64 bit or 32 bit. So that if the system is 32 bit, the following tag

`<linkerStartOption>\foo\${the.folder}\Microsoft SDK\lib</linkerStartOption>`

has the value `\foo\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\lib`, or if the system is 64 bit, have the link be the value `\foo\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDK\lib`.

The problem is currently my project uses `<activeByDefault>` tag to set a release version profile, which is being overwritten when the profile for determining 32 bit or 64 bit system is activated. This caused the properties determined by the release profile to not be available and cause the Java native build to fail. The release profile is used for release and there is also a debug profile used for debugging, which uses different `<linkerStartOption>` flags, so I don't want to just have release profile flags always be active.

My question is if there is a way for my native Java application to determine the 32-bit Windows Program Files path without deactivating the release profile triggered as `<activeByDefault>`?

Here is my profile for determining system architecture:

```
<profile>
  <id>architecture</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>Windows</family>
      <arch>amd64</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <the.folder>${env.PROGRAMFILES(X86)}</the.folder>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Here is the release profile being overwritten:

```
<profile>
  <id>release</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <options>/foo -bar</options>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? if the profile `release` should always be activated, it should not be a profile, but properties. If you want to run a release execution and let the other profiles use their own activation, drop `activeByDefault` and run `mvn -Prelease`

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Sorry, the release profile should be active unless specified otherwise. I also have a debug profile that sets flags different from release profile using the linkerStartOption tags, so I don't want the release flags used for debug profile. Is there a way to do what you said without having to do mvn -Prelease by changing something in the parent pom.xml?